# Angularjs, lexerr Lexer Error : How to pass email address (regex) to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I've been trying to do is to send an email address to a function of Angularjs.

Here is a part of my code.

```
<script>
//For the sake of simplicity, I omitted the descriptions for the module and service
this.sendEmail = function(id, emailAddress){
        // The "emailAddress" parameter is required.
};
</script>

<button name="sendEmail" type="button" ng-click='tc.sendEmail({{$id}}, {{$order->email_address}})'>Send the mail</button>
```

I'm using Laravel, and I'm 100% sure that `{{$id}}` and `{{$order->email_address}})` contain the right values.

However, this causes an error, `Error: $parse:lexerr
Lexer Error`.

> angular.js:12520Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2043-43%20%5B%40%5D&p2=tc.sendEmail(1025%2C%20example1000%40gmail.com)

As you may notice, the values are `1025` and `example1000@gmail.com` respectively. I thought this error can be escaped by covering them with `\`, but this was not a solution.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed that you must have different symbols(other than `{{}}`) for bindings.

You should need to wrap email with `'`(single/double quote) to avoid `$parser` error, because when `{{$order->email_address}}` gets evaluated to actual email address suppose `YMD@xyz.com`, so it wasn't wrap inside `'`/`"`, so it tries to search variable name `YMD@xyz.com` inside a scope & throws an error.

```
ng-click="tc.sendEmail({{$id}}, '{{$order->email_address}}')"
```